# Improve curve fitting log

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I try to make a fit of my curve. My raw data is in an xlsx file. I extract them using pandas. I want to do two different fit because there is a change in behavior from Ra = 1e6. We know that Ra is proportional to Nu**a. a = 0.25 for Ra <1e6 and if not a = 0.33.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import lmfit

data=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,dtype={'Ra': float})
print(data)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(data['Ra'].values, data['Nu_top'].values, label='Nu_top')
plt.scatter(data['Ra'].values, data['Nu_bottom'].values, label='Nu_bottom')
plt.errorbar(data['Ra'].values, data['Nu_top'].values , yerr=data['Ecart type top'].values, linestyle="None") 
plt.errorbar(data['Ra'].values, data['Nu_bottom'].values , yerr=data['Ecart type bot'].values, linestyle="None")

def func(x,a):
    return 10**(np.log10(x)/a)

"""maxX = max(data['Ra'].values)
minX = min(data['Ra'].values)
maxY = max(data['Nu_top'].values)
minY = min(data['Nu_top'].values)
maxXY = max(maxX, maxY)
parameterBounds = [-maxXY, maxXY]"""

from lmfit import Model
mod = Model(func)
params = mod.make_params(a=0.25)
ret = mod.fit(data['Nu_top'].head(10).values, params, x=data['Ra'].head(10).values)
print(ret.fit_report())

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data['Ra'].head(10).values, 
data['Nu_top'].head(10).values, sigma=data['Ecart type top'].head(10).values,
 absolute_sigma=True, p0=[0.25])
plt.plot(data['Ra'].head(10).values, func(data['Ra'].head(10).values, *popt),
 'r-', label='fit: a=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data['Ra'].tail(4).values, data['Nu_top'].tail(4).values,
 sigma=data['Ecart type top'].tail(4).values, 
absolute_sigma=True, p0=[0.33])
plt.plot(data['Ra'].tail(4).values, func(data['Ra'].tail(4).values, *popt),
 'b-', label='fit: a=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

print(pcov)

plt.grid
plt.title("Nusselt en fonction de Ra")
plt.xlabel('Ra')
plt.ylabel('Nu')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So I use the log: `logRa = a * logNu`.
Ra = x axis
Nu = y axis
That's why I defined my function func in this way.

my two fit are not all correct as you can see. I have a covariance equal to [0.00010971]. So I had to do something wrong but I don't see it. I need help please.
Here the data file:
[data.xlsx](https://github.com/Suntoryy/Help/blob/master/data.xlsx)
[image]

Comment: Would you please add the data or a link to the data?

Comment: It's good I put a link to have the file data.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With polyfit I have better results.
With my code I open the file and I calculate log (Ra) and log (Nu) then plot (log (Ra), log (Nu)) in log scale.
I'm supposed to have a = 0.25 for Ra <1e6 and if not a = 0.33

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10
from numpy import polyfit
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

data=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,dtype={'Ra': float})
print(data)

x=np.log10(data['Ra'].values)
y1=np.log10(data['Nu_top'].values)
y2=np.log10(data['Nu_bottom'].values)
x2=np.log10(data['Ra'].head(11).values)
y4=np.log10(data['Nu_top'].head(11).values)
x3=np.log10(data['Ra'].tail(4).values)
y5=np.log10(data['Nu_top'].tail(4).values)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(x, y1, label='Nu_top')
plt.scatter(x, y2, label='Nu_bottom')

plt.errorbar(x, y1 , yerr=data['Ecart type top'].values, linestyle="None") 
plt.errorbar(x, y2 , yerr=data['Ecart type bot'].values, linestyle="None")


"""a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.float)
weights = np.insert(a,0,1E10)"""



coefs = poly.polyfit(x2, y4, 1)
print(coefs)
ffit = poly.polyval(x2, coefs)
plt.plot(x2, ffit, label='fit: b=%5.3f, a=%5.3f' % tuple(coefs))

absError = ffit - x2

SE = np.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = np.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(x2))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
print()
print('Predicted value at x=0:', ffit[0])
print()


coefs = poly.polyfit(x3, y5, 1)
ffit = poly.polyval(x3, coefs)
plt.plot(x3, ffit, label='fit: b=%5.3f, a=%5.3f' % tuple(coefs))

plt.grid
plt.title("Nusselt en fonction de Ra")
plt.xlabel('log10(Ra)')
plt.ylabel('log10(Nu)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

My problem is solved, I managed to fit my curves with more or less correct results

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the data values for Ra are large, and after scaling them I performed an equation search - here is my result with code. I use the standard scipy genetic algorithm module differential_evolution to determine initial parameter values for curve_fit(), and that module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space which requires bounds within which to search. It is much easier to give ranges for the initial parameter estimates than to find specific values. This equation works well for both nu_top and nu_bottom, note that the plots are not log scaled as it is unnecessary in this example.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import pandas
import warnings

filename = 'data.xlsx'
data=pandas.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,dtype={'Ra': float})

# notice the Ra scaling by 10000.0
xData = data['Ra'].values / 10000.0
yData = data['Nu_bottom']


def func(x, a, b, c): # "Combined Power And Exponential" from zunzun.com
    return a * numpy.power(x, b) * numpy.exp(c * x)


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 10.0]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 10.0]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 10.0]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea and your code. It will help me to solve my physical problem in another way.

Comment: Totally awesome, gnarly statistical dude!

Comment: The Rsquared is the correlation coefficient ?

Comment: R-squared is the square of the correlation coefficient. I calculate the R-squared (R2) value as "R2 = 1.0 - (regression_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" and use it to tell me what fraction of the dependent data variance is explained by the model. R-squared is exact for straight lines, and both approximate and useful for curved lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here I put my data x and y in log10 (). The graph is in log scale. So normally I should have two affine functions with a coefficient of 0.25 and 0.33. I change the function func in your program James and bounds for b and c but I have no good result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10, log
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import lmfit

data=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,dtype={'Ra': float})
print(data)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(np.log10(data['Ra'].values), np.log10(data['Nu_top'].values), label='Nu_top')
plt.scatter(np.log10(data['Ra'].values), np.log10(data['Nu_bottom'].values), label='Nu_bottom')

plt.errorbar(np.log10(data['Ra'].values), np.log10(data['Nu_top'].values) , yerr=data['Ecart type top'].values, linestyle="None") 
plt.errorbar(np.log10(data['Ra'].values), np.log10(data['Nu_bottom'].values) , yerr=data['Ecart type bot'].values, linestyle="None")

def func(x,a):
    return a*x

maxX = max(data['Ra'].values)
minX = min(data['Ra'].values)
maxY = max(data['Nu_top'].values)
minY = min(data['Nu_top'].values)
maxXY = max(maxX, maxY)
parameterBounds = [-maxXY, maxXY]

from lmfit import Model
mod = Model(func)
params = mod.make_params(a=0.25)
ret = mod.fit(np.log10(data['Nu_top'].head(10).values), params, x=np.log10(data['Ra'].head(10).values))
print(ret.fit_report())



popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, np.log10(data['Ra'].head(10).values), np.log10(data['Nu_top'].head(10).values), sigma=data['Ecart type top'].head(10).values, absolute_sigma=True, p0=[0.25])
plt.plot(np.log10(data['Ra'].head(10).values), func(np.log10(data['Ra'].head(10).values), *popt), 'r-', label='fit: a=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, np.log10(data['Ra'].tail(4).values), np.log10(data['Nu_top'].tail(4).values), sigma=data['Ecart type top'].tail(4).values, absolute_sigma=True, p0=[0.33])
plt.plot(np.log10(data['Ra'].tail(4).values), func(np.log10(data['Ra'].tail(4).values), *popt), 'b-', label='fit: a=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

print(pcov)

plt.grid
plt.title("Nusselt en fonction de Ra")
plt.xlabel('log10(Ra)')
plt.ylabel('log10(Nu)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]